# Create folder mounting between localhost and minikube services

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I have some trouble creating a mounting folder between my local host (Ubuntu 20.04) to my services running on minikube.
I want multiple containers to share files (one container will write, and the others will read).

The services have a simple Python script that gets a path to a folder:

```py
with open('/MountedFolder/MyFile.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write("New Text")
```

And I have a simple deployment file that looks like that:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: info-deployment
  labels:
    app: info
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: info
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: info
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: info
        image: info:1.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8081
```

I succeeded in getting a mounted folder as a URL (`http://localhost`). Using this guide:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/

However, I am looking for a “path” like mounting (`/MountedFolder/MyFile.txt`) on the host.

Is it possible? If so, how?

Comment: Can you use a different approach to communicate between services?  If you ever try to scale this beyond one node, it's actually kind of tricky to get a volume that's accessible from more than one of them, and there are a lot of practical synchronization problems around sharing files.  If you're not planning to scale beyond one node, plain Docker might be much easier to use than Kubernetes.

Answer (score 0):

If you used the PVC-Guide (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/)

Change your python to:

```py
with open('[mountPath]/MyFile.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write("New Text")
```

The file will then be created under: `[mountPath]/MyFile.txt`, where [mountPath] is set in your container spec. From pod viewpoint.

```
volumeMounts:
   - mountPath: "/usr/share/nginx/html"
     name: task-pv-storage
```

On the host you should find the file under:

`"/mnt/data/MyFile.txt"`